# Django-rest framework structure not capturing post or put request

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using django-rest-framework to make a [JSON-API](http://jsonapi.org/). Currently API works with GET and DELETE request but not with POST and PUT request. Somehow post or put parameters don't get captured. Here is my serializer and my view.

serializers.py

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   attribute = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
      model = Snippet
      fields = ('id','attribute')

   def get_attribute(self, obj): 
      return {
         'code': obj.code, 
       }
```

views.py

```
from resources.snippets.models import Snippet
from .serializers import SnippetSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
   serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
```

When I made http request with posted parameters  -  http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippet/, { 'code' : 'testtest'},  api creates a new snippet instance without the posted parameters. Likewise, when I made PUT request to http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippet/1, the data doesn't get updated with the put parameters.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the message/error you receive on sending a `post/put` request? Did any specific error popup?

Comment: it didn't show any errors. As @spectras said, I didn't include the parameters in serializer, which caused them being ignored whenever I made POST or PUT request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your serializer has no writable fields.

```
fields = ('id','attribute')
```

You define it there to only have two attributes, the first of which is the id, and the second being a read-only attribute. Both get logically ignored when writing (id is overridden from the url and read-only is, well, read-only).

If you want to be able to write other fields, you must include them as well. If you still don't want them output when you `GET` the object, you may add them as write-only fields:

```
    fields = ('id', 'attribute', 'foo', 'bar')
    extra_kwargs = {
        'foo': {'write_only': True},
        'bar': {'write_only': True},
    }
```